# Is there an equivalent of aspectj-maven-plugin for gradle that works in android?

Tags: android, gradle, aspectj

Working with maven and a pure java project, I was able to use codehaus' aspectj-maven-plugin to weave (compile time) aspects (from a library I build) into my annotated classes.

I'd like to do the same with an android project (gradle build), but can't seem to find much documentation.

I've found the  android-apt project [here](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/), but can't wrap my head around how to use it with aspectj weaving.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found this project: [eveoh/gradle-aspectj](https://github.com/eveoh/gradle-aspectj) which should help you out. I am still trying to get it setup for my project, however. GL =)